# Weird audit2why message caused by SELinux

Tags: security, scp, selinux

When I run **audit2why** to see why there is a failure when trying to upload files via SCP to folder */foo/bar* on a remote server which results in *access denied to folder /foo/bar*, I get the following text:

```
Was caused by:
                Unknown - would be allowed by active policy
                Possible mismatch between this policy and the one 
under which the audit message was generated.

                Possible mismatch between current in-memory 
boolean settings vs. permanent ones.
```

I know that this is definitely being caused by **SELinux** as when I run the command:

```
setenforce 0
```

I can upload the files via SCP to */foo/bar*. Also of note, if I SSH in and **cd** to folder */foo/bar* with SELinux enabled I can create a file in this folder.

How would I debug to see what is causing the exact issue within SELinux?

**EDIT**

Here is the output of `ls -lZ` of */foo/bar*

```
drwxrwx--T. root foo-users user_u:object_r:default_t:s0     bar
```

and the output of an *AVC denial* from `audit2allow`

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1519304988.434:6984): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=26506 comm="scp" name="event-20180203.log.gz" dev="dm-4" ino=7260 scontext=user_u:user_r:user_t:s0 tcontext=user_u:object_r:default_t:s0 tclass=file
    Was caused by:
        Unknown - would be allowed by active policy
        Possible mismatch between this policy and the one under which the audit message was generated.
```

Comment: This is most probably caused by incompatible label on destination directory. May you post the denial AVC (  sudo grep denied /var/log/audit/audit.log ) or the result of audit2allow result ?

Comment: due to the nature of the work, I can not post a word for word one, but I can post a full line with names changed if that would work? @tonioc

Comment: The important bits in the log are the security contexts for files/process. The file context for /foo/bar would also be useful.

Comment: @tonioc added the output from an AVC denial

Comment: @sebasth added the context for the /foo/bar folder gotten from ls -lZ

Answer (score 2):

what AVC says:

```
$ echo "type=AVC msg=audit(1519304988.434:6984): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=26506 comm="scp" name="event-20180203.log.gz" dev="dm-4" ino=7260 scontext=user_u:user_r:user_t:s0 tcontext=user_u:object_r:default_t:s0 tclass=file" |audit2allow     
#============= user_t ==============
#!!!! WARNING: 'default_t' is a base type.
allow user_t default_t:file write;
```

==> A process running in user_t SElinux context type is trying to write to a directory having default_t type.

Alternatives to fix this are either:

- relabel destination directory to permit user_t writing to it:

  $ sesearch -s user_t --allow |grep " file.*write"

  will show allowed target context for file write operation. For example, foo/bar might be relabelled to ssh_home_t which is in permitted list:

  $ sudo chcon -R -t ssh_home_t /foo/bar
- or if you can, change the destination directory to a permitted one.
- or create a new rule using audit2allow to bypass the control, but this opens  permissions, breaking the SELinux aim, so should be the last choice. 'see http://selinuxproject.org/page/Audit2allowRecipe )

Answer (score 0):

```
Unknown - would be allowed by active policy
Possible mismatch between this policy and the one 
under which the audit message was generated.
```

I got the same message after having applied a corrective policy. All the previous audited avc could not be explained since the new policy would have permit them.
Check if newer events still occurs.